# How do I escape only single quotes?

Tags: php, escaping

I am writing some JavaScript code that uses a string rendered with PHP. How can I escape single quotes (and only single quotes) in my PHP string?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myElement').html('say hello to <?php echo $mystringWithSingleQuotes ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to escape more than single quotes.  Newlines, for one.  You might do well with something like `addcslashes($mystringWithSingleQuotes, "'\"\r\n\\\t\0..\37")`

Comment: Instead of handling the escaping yourself, use `json_encode()` to get a valid Javascript string (and remove your outer single quotes).

Comment: @Frank: Can you post your answer as an answer instead of as a comment? Proper answers in comments can not be selected and therefore creates fake "unanswered questions".

Comment: Why can't you just double quotes in `.html()` instead of wrapping in single quotes? the php expansion will happen regardless. Been doing this for everything from attributes on elements and imports as well as variable assignments inside script blocks.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Quite simply: `echo str_replace('\'', '\\\'', $myString);`
However, I'd suggest use of [JSON](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [`json_encode()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function as it will be more reliable (quotes new lines for instance):

```
<?php $data = array('myString' => '...'); ?>

<script>
   var phpData = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
   alert(phpData.myString);
</script>
```

Comment: All of the answers that say `str_replace("'","\\'", $string)` and similar are incorrect. Consider the string \' It will be replaced with \\' and this will cause an injection vulnerability. Instead use json_encode as Crozin suggests.

Comment: Thank you.. I knew this but I was facing problem because I was trying to do `JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($data);?>');` and it was failing because there was a single quote inside data. Later I came to know there is no need to use `JSON.parse` here.

Comment: json_encode could get you into trouble if the json extension was not installed. Read my solution below using strtr(..)

Comment: @BasilMusa As of PHP 5.2 JSON extension is bundled by default ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php)) so I wouldn't be worried about that.

Comment: @DavidM. except that the OP never mentions JSON and was very specific about what he needs.

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for that because I had to return a string from PHP to JS, and this was just the way to go. THank you!

Answer (score 42):

If you want to escape characters with a `\`, you have `addcslashes()`. For example, if you want to escape only single quotes like the question, you can do:

```
echo addcslashes($value, "'");
```

And if you want to escape `'`, `"`, `\`, and `nul` (the byte null), you can use `addslashes()`:

```
echo addslashes($value);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out [addcslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) to escape arbitrary characters.

Answer (score 20):

```
str_replace("'", "\'", $mystringWithSingleQuotes);
```

Answer (score 18):

In some cases, I just convert it into ENTITIES:

```
                        // i.e.,  $x= ABC\DEFGH'IJKL
$x = str_ireplace("'",  "&apos;", $x);
$x = str_ireplace("\\", "&bsol;", $x);
$x = str_ireplace('"',  "&quot;", $x);
```

On the HTML page, the visual output is the same:

```
ABC\DEFGH'IJKL
```

However, it is sanitized in source.

Answer (score 10):

Use the native function `htmlspecialchars`. It will escape from all special character. If you want to escape from a quote specifically, use with `ENT_COMPAT` or `ENT_QUOTES`. Here is the example:

```
$str = "Jane & 'Tarzan'";
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_COMPAT); // Will only convert double quotes
echo "<br>";

echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES); // Converts double and single quotes
echo "<br>";

echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_NOQUOTES); // Does not convert any quotes
```

The output would be like this:

```
Jane &amp; 'Tarzan'<br>
Jane &amp; &#039;Tarzan&#039;<br>
Jane &amp; 'Tarzan'
```

Read more in *[PHP htmlspecialchars() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp)*

Answer (score 8):

To replace only single quotes, use this simple statement:

```
$string = str_replace("'", "\\'", $string);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [addcslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) function to get this done like so:

```
echo addcslashes($text, "'\\");
```

Answer (score 2):

After a long time fighting with this problem, I think I have found a better solution.

The combination of two functions makes it possible to escape a string to use as HTML.

One, to escape double quote if you use the string inside a JavaScript function call; and a second one to escape the single quote, avoiding those simple quotes that go around the argument.

**Solution:**

```
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($string))
```

**Solve:**

- a PHP line created to call a JavaScript function like

> echo
>   'onclick="javascript_function(\'' . mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($string))"

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following function. It replaces the following:

Single quote ['] with a slash and a single quote [\'].

Backslash [\] with two backslashes [\\]

```
function escapePhpString($target) {
    $replacements = array(
            "'" => '\\\'',
            "\\" => '\\\\'
    );
    return strtr($target, $replacements);
}
```

You can modify it to add or remove character replacements in the $replacements array. For example, to replace \r\n, it becomes "\r\n" => "\r\n" and "\n" => "\n".

```
/**
 * With new line replacements too
 */
function escapePhpString($target) {
    $replacements = array(
            "'" => '\\\'',
            "\\" => '\\\\',
            "\r\n" => "\\r\\n",
            "\n" => "\\n"
    );
    return strtr($target, $replacements);
}
```

The neat feature about strtr is that it will prefer long replacements.

Example, "Cool\r\nFeature" will escape \r\n rather than escaping \n along.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are doing with your data, but you could always try:

```
$string = str_replace("'", "%27", $string);
```

I use this whenever strings are sent to a database for storage.

%27 is the encoding for the ' character, and it also helps to prevent disruption of GET requests if a single `'` character is contained in a string sent to your server.  I would replace ' with %27 in both JavaScript and PHP just in case someone tries to manually send some data to your PHP function.

To make it prettier to your end user, just run an inverse replace function for all data you get back from your server and replace all %27 substrings with `'`.

Happy injection avoiding!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. Silly, but simple.

```
$singlequote = "'";
$picturefile = getProductPicture($id);

echo showPicture('.$singlequote.$picturefile.$singlequote.');
```

I was working on outputting HTML that called JavaScript code to show a picture...