# Escape only single quotes (leave double quotes alone) with htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php, escaping, htmlspecialchars

I know there are other ways of of escaping only single quotes ([such as this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269188/how-to-escape-only-single-quotes)), but it appears to me that there should be a way using [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

According to the manual, it should be some combination of their constants, but based on their explanations, I don't see it.

Is it possible to escape only single quotes, leaving the double quotes alone, with `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: Why do you need this? It seems like a problem to me.

Comment: if it's just single quotes, then use str_replace

Comment: [This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#99185) might help

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Why do I need this? I'm using "Google Visualizations: Table", which requires me to send the data via javascript. I've wrote a PHP function to build this javascript from data passed to the function, and I'd rather just have the PHP function internally escape the single quotes (used to mark a string in the passed javascript to Google), rather than having to escape the data before I pass it to the function. But, sometimes that data passed to the PHP function contains HTML, which I do not want to escape. Make sense?

Comment: If you're sending JavaScript use `json_encode`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
str_replace("'", "\\'", $string);
```

There.

Or, use `ENT_QUOTES`

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: I seriously doubt `\'` is the intended replacement string, if the goal is to put it in a HTML document.

Comment: If he's trying to escape single quotes, that would be the intended string.

Comment: Escaping single quotes to put it in a `'`-delimited attribute means changing them to `&#39;` (or equivalent, if there is an equivalent -- I'm not sure). Your other suggestion, `ENT_QUOTES`, also converts double quote characters, which the question asks to leave alone.

Comment: Final answer: used a combo of @hvd and Norse: `str_replace("'", "&#39;");`, although I guess the technically correct answer to my question is `no, you cannot escape only single quotes with htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 13):

Here's the combination of constants you're looking for.

```
$escaped_string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES & ~ENT_COMPAT, $encoding);
```

This will escape `& ' < >`, but leaves `"` alone. `ENT_QUOTES & ~ENT_COMPAT` is bit  manipulation language meaning "*both quotes, minus the double quotes*".

This works because of how these constants are defined. [php-src/ext/standard/html.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/html.h)

```
#define ENT_HTML_QUOTE_NONE         0
#define ENT_HTML_QUOTE_SINGLE       1
#define ENT_HTML_QUOTE_DOUBLE       2

#define ENT_COMPAT      ENT_HTML_QUOTE_DOUBLE
#define ENT_QUOTES      (ENT_HTML_QUOTE_DOUBLE | ENT_HTML_QUOTE_SINGLE)
#define ENT_NOQUOTES    ENT_HTML_QUOTE_NONE
```

Why would you ever want to escape single quotes, but not double quotes? Well, the inverse of the reason you'd escape double quotes, but not single quotes: because you've got a string with lots of `"` double quotes and only a few `'` single quotes, so you'd like to stick it in a `'`-delimited string.

An example:

```
<div data-myobject='<?= htmlspecialchars(json_encode($myobject), ENT_QUOTES & ~ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') ?>'
```

`json_encode()` creates lots of double quotes, so it makes sense to stick the result in a single-quote delimited attribute, and leave the double quotes unescaped.

Comment: I know this is an old and closed question, but I couldn't find an answer to the original question anywhere, so I decided to post one.

Comment: This should be the answer. I prefer `ENT_HTML5 | ENT_QUOTES & ~ENT_COMPAT` myself.

Answer (score 1):

Use htmlspecialchars(...)

Then str_replace(...) on a double quote