# Modifying my PHP regex for "escapeshellcmd"

Tags: php, regex, shell, preg-match

I am trying to build a filter for sorting/removing files;

However, upon testing I have noticed 2 files which are getting through the net despite being named with a "(Japan)" country identifier at the end. I think this is because of their strange characters (a dollar sign in one and 3 periods in a row in the other)

The 2 files are:

```
Quiz$Millionaire - Waku Waku Party (Japan).zip
...Iru! (Japan).zip
```

I get the error below when running the script. It echo's the file correctly, but then when attempting the `mv` it reports it with "$Millionaire" missing from the middle of the string!

```
Quiz$Millionaire (Japan) (v1.0).zip is a foreign language release. Moved to Removed folder.
mv: cannot stat 'Quiz (Japan) (v1.0).zip': No such file or directory
```

Unfortunately for the other file (...Iru! (Japan).zip) I don't even get a match/echo

I have been told I need to use `$thisGame = escapeshellcmd($thisGame);` in the code below, but when I do it messes up my regex matching for everything else - so I think I have to modify my regex - but I am a beginner and don't really know how to fix it! Many thanks in advance for your help - code below:

```
$gameList = trim(shell_exec("ls -1"));
$gameArray = explode("\n", $gameList);

shell_exec('mkdir -p Removed');

// Do this magic for every file
foreach ($gameArray as $thisGame)
{
    if (!$thisGame) continue;
    // Probably already been removed
    if (!file_exists($thisGame)) continue;

    // Non-Engish speaking countries e.g. (France) or (Japan)
    if (preg_match('%\((Asia|Austria|Brazil|China|Denmark|Finland|France|Germany|Greece|Hungary|Israel|Italy|Japan|Japan, Asia|Korea|Netherlands|Norway|Poland|Portugal|Russia|Scandinavia|Spain|Sweden)\)%', $thisGame))
    {
        echo "{$thisGame} is a foreign language release. Moved to Removed folder.\n";
        shell_exec("mv \"{$thisGame}\" Removed/");
        continue;
    }

}
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You may want to remove `escapeshellcmd` and use single quotation marks in your `shell_exec` around `{$thisGame}` to prevent any shell expansion.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can fix my regex?

Comment: You don't need other changes.

Comment: Hi Revo, could you show me an example of what you mean? Many thanks!

Comment: Hey, `shell_exec("mv '{$thisGame}' Removed/");`

Comment: Hey @revo - yay thankyou. It is now being removed. However the file "`...Iru! (Japan).zip`" is still not being recognized by the filter :-(

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't get matched by `preg_match`?

Comment: Yep, for some reason the "..." is messing up the `preg_match` - or it could be the "!" :(

Comment: I can't reproduce https://3v4l.org/259RV

Comment: Fixed it. It needed `ls -a -1` to list the files starting with a period, with just `ls -1` it was never passed to the pregmatch. Many thanks again buddy.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is causing other errors in the matching :-(

For example: https://i.imgur.com/oZLHY3Q.png

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: You're right. Then take care about single quotes. You should escape them beforehand.

Comment: Hi Revo, How do I do that in terms of modifing the regex? Sorry I am a newbie :(

Comment: You don't have to modify the regex but escape single quotes in file name. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591027/escape-only-single-quotes-leave-double-quotes-alone-with-htmlspecialchars

Comment: I'm afriad I don't know how to do that in terms of modifying my code. I have gone back to `shell_exec("mv \"{$thisGame}\" Removed/");` for the time being as it filters everything except filenames with the dollar...