# PHP trying to escape single quotes

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating a music player. But the PHP just messes up filenames that have a singlequote in it. How can I fix this?

The first code is my current PHP.
The second code is how i want the output to be.

```
// integer starts at 0 before counting
$i = 0; 
$dir = 'music/';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
        if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
        echo "<span class='song' id='".$file."' onClick='playSong(\"".addslashes($file)."\");'>".$file."</span><br />";
    }
}
```

At first I did HTML, But now I want to use PHP so i can just drag songs into a folder and they get automaticly added to the list.

This is how the HTML was, which is how I want the output from the PHP to be.

```
<span id="Martin Garrix - Animals" onClick="playSong('Martin Garrix - Animals');">Martin Garrix - Animals</span>
<br />
<span id="TryHardNinja - Doin' it grand" onClick="playSong('TryHardNinja - Doin\' it grand');">TryHardNinja - Doin' it grand</span>
<br />
<span id="TryHardNinja - Calling All Ghosts" onClick="playSong('TryHardNinja - Calling All Ghosts');">TryHardNinja - Calling All Ghosts</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the quotes around:

```
echo '<span class="song" id="'.$file.'" onClick="playSong(\''.addslashes($file).'\');">'.$file.'</span><br />';
```

PS: I'm also not really sure, if you need the `addslashes`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick awnser, I feel stupid for not trying that earlier.

Will make this an accepted awnser in 5 mins (cannot accept an awnser within such short time)

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML ASCII code for the single quote:

```
&#39;
```

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> But the PHP just messes up filenames that have a singlequote in it.

But you code itself is adding the slashes via [`addslashes`](http://www.php.net/addslashes) in this line:

```
echo "<span class='song' id='".$file."' onClick='playSong(\"".addslashes($file)."\");'>".$file."</span><br />";
```

Looking at your HTML it seems that the reason you are adding `addslashes` might be connected to your HTML tag parameters (ie: `class='song'` & such)  having single quotes in them.  So I would recommend you use double quotes on them & just remove the `addslashes` entirely:

```
echo '<span class="song" id="'.$file.'" onClick="playSong("'.$file.'");'>'.$file.'</span><br />';
```

Or you can use `preg_replace` instead of `addslashes` to change all single quotes in your `$file` string to be the ASCII HTML entity for it (`&#39;`) instead:

```
echo "<span class='song' id='".$file."' onClick='playSong(\"".preg_replace('/\'/', '&#39;', $file)."\");'>".$file."</span><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `addslashes`, use [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities), which also avoids a lot of unrelated trouble, for example different encodings when you have song titles that are not in english.

```
echo '<span class="song" id="'.$file.'" onClick="playSong(\''.htmlentities($file, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'\');">'.htmlentities($file, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'</span><br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [How to escape only single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269188/how-to-escape-only-single-quotes), use json_encode(), which is injection-safe:

```
$my_str = json_encode("using single quote here: '",JSON_HEX_APOS);

echo $my_str;
```

this gives you the output:

```
using single quote here: \u0027
```

which works the same as \' in JavaScript.