# Convert PHP string to javascript string

Tags: javascript, php

For example, I have this php string: "2015-06-26". I want to assign it to a javascript var.

I tried with String("2015-06-26"), but it's substracting the numbers, so the result is this: "1983".

How am I supposed to do it? Thanks.

Comment: and what is the command that you wrote?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse date without timezone javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545708/parse-date-without-timezone-javascript)

Comment: @shoover This has nothing to do with parsing dates. He's just trying to pass a literal string from PHP to JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` to convert any PHP value to the corresponding Javascript literal:

```
var datestring = <?php echo json_encode($datestring); ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

what about that?

```
var date = '<?php echo str_replace("'", "\'", $yourstring);?>';
```

Comment: On https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269188/how-do-i-escape-only-single-quotes David M. explains this is subject to code injection: if your string contains \'; and some code then it gets converted to \\'; and some code  and date = '\\'; is interpreted as a single character string and the code gets executed.