# SQL error due to ' in variable contents

Tags: php, mysql

Good Morning,

I have an issue with SQL Insert command from php. I'm trying the following code:

```
$TeamMatchTable = "INSERT INTO Team Match Table 
                  (LineupForward) VALUES ('$HomeLineupForward')";`
```

However the contents of the `$HomeLineupForward` variable is: `Alexandre D'Acol;`

This is resulting in an error because of the `'`.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You should not quote your column name and you should definitely use a prepared statement.

Comment: Is the table really called `Team Match Table` with spaces? Also, `LineupForward` should not be surrounded by single quotes but backticks.

Comment: You can have a look on, http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269188/how-to-escape-only-single-quotes for characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? `PDO` or `mysqli_` or `mysql_*`

Comment: Since you're basically SQL injecting yourself, I marked this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$HomeLineupForward= mysql_real_escape_string($HomeLineupForward);

$TeamMatchTable = "INSERT INTO Team Match Table ('LineupForward') VALUES ('$HomeLineupForward')";
```

Comment: mysql_* is depreciated as of PHP 7. Plz don't use.

Comment: thanks @Matt . he can try this mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $HomeLineupForward);

Comment: @TariqHusain _he can try this mysqli_real_escape_string_ Only if he is connecting with `mysqli_` and not `mysql_` or `PDO` But of course we dont know which it is yet because nobody has asks him!

Comment: I am connected using mysqli

Comment: have you tried this mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $HomeLineupForward); ? @JustinSpiteri