# Escaping single quotes in a URL link

Tags: php, html

I have a link that is sent throw some PHP code:

```
echo "<a href='" . $galerry . "#" . apastro(get_title($primid)) . "'     class='linkorange'>voir sa galerie</a>";
```

`$galerry` links to another page.

`get_title($primid)` is the id of a specific element in `$galerry` page.

And the mechanism works fine until one of the elements id has a single quote in it. Which makes sense as it would interrupt the echo function.

This is why I have the apastro function:

```
function apastro($phrase){
    $phrase1 = str_replace("'", "\'", $phrase);
    return $phrase1;
}
```

Yet, the `\` before the single quote isn't helping...

So let's say the link redirects to the element with id="l'aro" on the page `something.php`. Then the URL will be `something.php#l\`.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269188/how-to-escape-only-single-quotes

Comment: You can use `urlencode()`

Comment: `$galerry`? Not `$gallery`?

Answer (score 7):

> it would interrupt the echo function

It wouldn't. It would break a string literal delimited by `'` characters, but your string literal is delimited with `"` characters. In this case, it is breaking the HTML attribute value which *is* delimited by `'` characters.

`\` is not an escape character for URLs or HTML.

Use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) to make a string safe to put into a URL.

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to make a string safe to put into an HTML attribute.

```
$title = get_title($primid);
$urlsafe_title = urlencode($title);
$url = $galerry . "#" . $urlsafe_title;
$htmlsafe_url = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);

echo "<a href='$htmlsafe_url' class='linkorange'>voir sa galerie</a>";
```

Comment: This is the best answer you'll get. I use this all the time.

Answer (score -2):

If you're looking to escape **single quotes only**, use double backslashes, as follows

```
$str = str_replace("'", "\\'", $str);
```