# PHP Value Not Display if variable text includes apostrophe

Tags: php

I have the following piece of PHP code as part of my site theme. Where I am stuck is, if the value of $sec_title contains an apostrophe, then the text doesn't display. But without an apostrophe, it contains fine. How can I amend this to prevent this issue?

```
<?php
if ( $sec_title ) {
echo do_shortcode( "[onex_section_header
title={$sec_title}
subtitle='{$sec_subtitle}']"
);
} ?>
```

Comment: try to add ￦ before '

Comment: Can you please show what does your do_shortcode function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269188/how-to-escape-only-single-quotes might help you. Try using json_encode()

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$sec_title = addslashes($sec_title)
```

before you echo or try switching the double and single quotes around as so

```
echo do_shortcode('[onex_section_header 
title={$sec_title} 
subtitle="{$sec_subtitle}"]'
);
```