# How to solve sql error " product portfolio has diversified to encompass a highly successful multi-brand' at line 1"

Tags: mysql

I am kind of new one for mysql and php. a week ago this code worked perfectly and when now I am trying it shows this error message

> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 's product portfolio has diversified to encompass a highly
>   successful multi-brand' at line 1

I search how to solve that after spending a whole day, but couldn't figure it out.
I have tried similar questions here in stackoverflow, Yet I am stucked here. 
A help would be really admired
Given below is my code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{       $company_name =$_POST['company_name'];
        $service =$_POST['service'];
        $email =$_POST['email'];
        $password =$_POST['password'];
        $details =$_POST['details'];

        $fileName = $_FILES['Filename']['name'];
        $fileName1 = $_FILES['Filename1']['name'];
        $fileName2 = $_FILES['Filename2']['name'];
        $fileName3 = $_FILES['Filename3']['name'];
        $fileName4 = $_FILES['Filename4']['name'];


        $target = "company_images/";                
        $fileTarget = $target.$fileName;    
        $fileTarget1 = $target.$fileName1;  
        $fileTarget2 = $target.$fileName2;  
        $fileTarget3 = $target.$fileName3;
        $fileTarget4 = $target.$fileName4;  
        $tempFileName = $_FILES["Filename"]["tmp_name"];
        $tempFileName1 = $_FILES["Filename1"]["tmp_name"];
        $tempFileName2 = $_FILES["Filename2"]["tmp_name"];
        $tempFileName3 = $_FILES["Filename3"]["tmp_name"];
        $tempFileName4 = $_FILES["Filename4"]["tmp_name"];
        $result = move_uploaded_file($tempFileName,$fileTarget);
        $result1 = move_uploaded_file($tempFileName1,$fileTarget1);
        $result2 = move_uploaded_file($tempFileName2,$fileTarget2);
        $result3 = move_uploaded_file($tempFileName3,$fileTarget3);
        $result4 = move_uploaded_file($tempFileName4,$fileTarget4);


        $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $folder="pdf_uploads/";

        // new file size in KB
        $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
        // new file size in KB

        // make file name in lower case
        $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
        // make file name in lower case

        $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);//anthima
        if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
        {

            $query = "INSERT INTO company_details( company_name,service, email, password, details,image_path,file_name,image_path1,file_name1,image_path2,file_name2,image_path3,file_name3,file,type,size,image_path4,file_name4) VALUES ('$company_name','$service','$email','$password','$details','$fileTarget','$fileName','$fileTarget1','$fileName1','$fileTarget2','$fileName2','$fileTarget3','$fileName3','$final_file','$file_type','$new_size','$fileTarget4','$fileName4')";
            $con->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($con));          


            mysqli_close($con);
}

}   
?>

<?php
```

Given below is the test data error

```
VALUES ('singer','Hardware','singer@gmail.com','singer','Singer has been in Sr' at line 1
```

Comment: Include the test data you are trying to insert

Comment: See? You're including the part of data in the error message instead of whatever you sent through the form (received in the `$_POST`)

Comment: @Alfabravo Thank you very much. I understood where was the error. Can you explain me how to save data with unscaped apostrphe. Please?

Comment: you have misplaced a `,` at the end on column names

Comment: @Sinto I removed that, even if the error message is there. This error has occured dues 's value in the submitted data.Now I want to solve that

Comment: @Sinto he was lucky the previous error never let him reach that misplaced comma :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you never sanitize anything and put the data straight into your query,

```
    $company_name =$_POST['company_name'];
    $service =$_POST['service'];
    $email =$_POST['email'];
    $password =$_POST['password'];
    $details =$_POST['details'];

...

$query = "INSERT INTO 
    company_details( company_name,service, email, password, details,image_path,file_name,image_path1,file_name1,image_path2,file_name2,image_path3,file_name3,file,type,size,image_path4,file_name4) 
    VALUES (
    '$company_name','$service','$email','$password','$details','$fileTarget','$fileName','$fileTarget1','$fileName1','$fileTarget2','$fileName2','$fileTarget3','$fileName3','$final_file','$file_type','$new_size','$fileTarget4','$fileName4'
    )";
```

your problem is most likely in the data

> 's product portfolio has diversified to encompass a highly successful multi-brand

Maybe you have unscaped apostrophes in your data, so you're kinda SQL-injecting yourself. The query ends before the string shown in the error.

The solution is to escape special chars before inserting like in this question: [How do I escape only single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269188/how-do-i-escape-only-single-quotes#6269254)

In your case, start with the details

```
$details = addcslashes($_POST['details'], "'");
```

or

```
$details = addslashes($_POST['details']);
```

But keep adding test scenarios for your code. E.g. what happens if company name gets something like `Mc'Donaldson`? What is the set of chars you want to accept for each field? Then you will know how to validate those fields and create your functions (or reuse something)

Comment: @sadee Updated the answer as well