# Handle special character ' in laravel blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my view page i had a button
`<button id="submit_btn" onclick="submitData('{{$data}}')">Save Data</button>`. If the `$data` contains special characters like `' or "` the script will be resulted in an error. How can i handle this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Is your data an array? A string? An array of strings?

Comment: $data is string. it may contain ' or "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape quote characters with [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

```
<button id="submit_btn" onclick="submitData('{{addslashes($data)}}')">Save Data</button>
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269188/how-do-i-escape-only-single-quotes)

Comment: Thank you @Mike Harrison. addslashes() works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
<button id="submit_btn" onclick="submitData({{$data}})">Save Data</button>
```