# How to add a url with single quotes in jira description

Tags: html, jira, python-jira

We have an automated job that add’s a url in the description of a jira ticket but the url has single quotes which is breaking the link …

[image]

Link as Text: `http://localhost:5601/app/?_g=(refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:'2019-10-30 10:00:33',to:'2019-10-31 10:00:33')))`

As shown in the pic the link is broken due to the single quote …if we try to add an escape character with ' (Html escape) the description already interprets it and we get a single quote and broken hyperlink

Appreciate the community help in resolving the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape only single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269188/how-do-i-escape-only-single-quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your URL in **brackets `[]`** and it will be recognized as a URL by JIRA. You can test this by switching your JIRA text editor to Text mode, adding the brackets, and switching to visual.

For more JIRA Text formatting help, see [Atlassian Documentation](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all).

**Textual representation**
[image: Textual representation]

**Visual representation**
[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed visuals and the answer! this is super helpful