# Shimming ES6/globaThis/fromEntries manually on browser/client side

Tags: javascript, firefox, es6-shim

For legacy purposes I'm running FF60. Some newer websites fail, complaining about stuff like `globalThis` or `fromEntries` because their framework requires so.

Can I somehow [shim](https://github.com/es-shims) these from my side? When I say "my side" I mean me, as a client, as a lone Firefox user, not web developer. From browser's side.
An extension? A user-script? Is this even doable?

Partially found the answer in [How to polyfill `globalThis` into older browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70777307/how-to-polyfill-globalthis-into-older-browsers) but polyfill.io is dead

Comment: You can [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) missing _APIs_ like `Object.fromEntries`, but not unsupported _syntax_.

Comment: I understand I can, I'm asking how would I do it on the client/browser side? I dont see away

Comment: Can you show us a chunk of code that you intended to add to your site?

Comment: I've updated the question because of some confusion

Comment: "An extension? A user-script?" Have you tried adding the shims to a userscript for example? Did it work?

Comment: You can use `FormData`.

Comment: @Andy they are required to be compiled with node for your dev environment/project, which is not applicable to browser in any way. That is the issue. [fromEntries](https://github.com/es-shims/Object.fromEntries) forexample